# Small coroutine class

Tags: c++, c++14, coroutines

What do you think about this?

```
#include <alloca.h>

#include <setjmp.h>

#include <cassert>

#include <functional>

template <::std::size_t N = 4096>
class coroutine
{
  jmp_buf env_in_;
  jmp_buf env_out_;

  bool running_{};

  char stack_[N];

public:
  coroutine() = default;

  auto running() const noexcept
  {
    return running_;
  }

  template <typename F, typename ...A>
  void run(F&& f, A&& ...a)
  {
    if (setjmp(env_in_))
    {
      return;
    }
    // else do nothing

    auto top(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&top));
    alloca(top - (stack_ + N));

    running_ = true;

    [this, f = ::std::forward<F>(f)](A&& ...a) __attribute__ ((noinline))
    {
      f(::std::ref(*this), ::std::forward<A>(a)...);

      running_ = false;

      yield();
    }(::std::forward<A>(a)...);
  }

  void yield() noexcept
  {
    if (setjmp(env_out_))
    {
      return;
    }
    else
    {
      longjmp(env_in_, 1);
    }
  }

  void resume()
  {
    assert(running_);
    if (setjmp(env_in_))
    {
      return;
    }
    else
    {
      longjmp(env_out_, 1);
    }
  }
};
```

Usage:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "coroutine.hpp"

int main()
{
  coroutine<> c;

  c.run([](decltype(c)& c)
    {
      for (int i{}; i != 3; ++i)
      {
        ::std::cout << i << ::std::endl;

        c.yield();
      }
    }
  );

  while (c.running())
  {
    c.resume();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT

Change

```
auto top(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&top));
```

to

```
char* top;
top = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&top);
```

Also check out an updated [version](https://github.com/user1095108/generic/blob/master/coroutine.hpp) of the code.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Mast there was a bug in there due to an old gcc bug, check the answer to my question. This is why I fixed the code, not because of some other reason. The code as it is will not compile on newer compilers without the fix.

Comment: You shall not invalidate answers. So I'll roll back the edit again. Feel free to post a follow-up question linking back to this question with more up-to-date code.

Comment: On second thought, I've only removed the moderator part. I'm just a community member who has been around for a while, not a moderator.

Comment: @Mast there is a serious bug in there without the edit. I don't need a follow-up question. The code won't compile without the edit.

Comment: Which is why the edit can stick. But changing code after receiving answers is against site policy for good reasons.

Comment: @Mast Not in case of serious bugs .(An exception to that would be if a user wrote a comment saying that your code is completely broken, and needs to be fixed before it can be reviewed.) This is exactly what happened.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to document your assumptions and/or intended use cases a little better. Right now, I don't see how anything based on `setjmp`/`longjmp` could actually implement a coroutine, since `longjmp` can only ever jump *upward* in the call-stack, never *downward*. (Really, it can't jump "downward" because there *is* no "downward": the only things below us on the call-stack are things that have already finished executing, and things which will execute in the future.)

Notice that "things which will execute in the future" includes "interrupt handlers". You might want to check whether your implementation plays well with [Unix signal handlers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#Handling_signals) — I suspect it does not.

---

```
alloca(top - (stack_ + N));
```

This is a red flag: you're calling `alloca` without assigning the result anywhere. A sufficiently smart compiler will just optimize away this useless call. (Yeah, *I* kinda get what you're trying to do... but the *compiler* is under no obligation to get it.) What you really need to do here is heap-allocate a buffer for your stack, and then somehow get the saved stack pointer in the `jmp_buf` to point to it.

And I only *kinda* see what you're doing here, anyway. Are you assuming that the `coroutine` object itself *must* be allocated on the stack? What happens if I make a global or `static` `coroutine` object?

---

```
[this, f = ::std::forward<F>(f)](A&& ...a) __attribute__ ((noinline))
```

The `__attribute__((noinline))` here is another red flag. This time I *don't* get what you're trying to do. What would break if this lambda's `operator()` got inlined?

Also, style nit: I've never seen anyone put a space after the word `__attribute__` before.

---

Other style nits:

```
auto running() const noexcept
```

`auto` is a strange way to spell `bool`. It's not saving you any bytes.

```
// else do nothing
```

The above comment is highly misleading, in that it's followed by 13 lines of really dense code — hardly "do nothing"! I'd delete that comment.

```
auto top(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&top));
```

I'm actually amazed that this works, given that the decltype of `&top` is not known at the time the RHS is parsed. ...Oh wait, yeah, it **doesn't** work. Both GCC and Clang reject this code.

```
for (int i{}; i != 3; ++i)
```

Kudos for using prefix increment. Everything else about this for-loop is pretty unusual, though. I strongly recommend looping over the range `[0,3)` like this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
```

---

API design suggestions:

- Empty angle brackets suck. I'd recommend something more like

  ```
  template <size_t N> class coroutine_with_size { ... }

  using coroutine = coroutine_with_size<4096>;
  ```
- It's unfortunate that your coroutine has to do all its own I/O; a better design would be like the one found in Javascript (and Python), where coroutines can yield values. Unfortunately, the ability to yield values causes a cascade of API changes. Look:

  ```
  c.run([](auto&& c) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
          c.yield(i);
      }
  });

  while (c.running())
  {
      int ii = c.resume();
      std::cout << ii << std::endl;
  }
  ```

Well, unless `c` is somehow "looking ahead" to determine the value it's going to return next time, `c.running()` doesn't really make sense anymore. We've got to have `c.resume()` do all the hard work, at which point we need a way to say "okay, no more data, please stop iterating". That is, we need a way for `c.resume()` to terminate execution but *not* return a value. This smells like an *exception*. So:

```
c.run([](auto&& c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        c.yield(i);
    }
});

while (true)
{
    try {
        int ii = c.resume();
        std::cout << ii << std::endl;
    } catch (const coroutine::done&) {
        break;
    }
}
```

But now what is `c.run()` actually doing? It can't be actually *starting to run* the provided lambda, because there's nowhere for us to stash the yielded result yet (we haven't gotten to `ii`'s declaration). So all it's really doing now is constructing the coroutine object and then returning immediately. That smells like a *constructor*. So:

```
auto c = coroutine([](auto&& c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        c.yield(i);
    }
});

while (true)
{
    try {
        int ii = c.resume();
        std::cout << ii << std::endl;
    } catch (const coroutine::done&) {
        break;
    }
}
```

And unfortunately now we've got *move-constructible* `coroutine` objects, and your entire implementation strategy falls apart even more than it had been. Crap!

---

...Speaking of which, **your current implementation provides defaulted copy and move constructors!** You should *definitely* delete those:

```
coroutine(const coroutine&) = delete;
coroutine& operator=(const coroutine&) = delete;
// move operations get deleted implicitly due to the above;
// but I wouldn't object to deleting them explicitly as well
```

---

Getting back to the API-design example: the next step in a Javascript-like design would be allowing `c.resume()` to *take input* values, as well as *yielding output* values. Mind you, I'm not sure what the implementation for this would look like in C++. It might not be 100% possible. :)

```
auto c = coroutine([](auto&& c, int step) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i += step) {
        step = c.yield(i);
    }
});

while (true)
{
    try {
        int ii = c.resume(1);
        std::cout << ii << std::endl;
    } catch (const coroutine::done&) {
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Okay, I think it's *not* 100% possible — not without templating the `coroutine` class on the "inputs" and "outputs" (args-to-resume and args-to-yield) that it expects. I've done my own toy implementation [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151211/bigger-coroutine-class) for comparison. Muddling through that implementation also helped me understand the undefined-behavior magic about which I complained at the top of this review.

---

At least in the trivial case you started with — a coroutine used only as a generator, and whose `c.resume()` takes no input values — it would make sense to provide a sort of `coroutine_generator_iterator` so that one could write simply

```
for (int ii : coroutine_generator_iterator(c)) {
    std::cout << ii << std::endl;
}
```

This `coroutine_generator_iterator` concept wouldn't be very useful for coroutines that were actually used as *co*routines, e.g. passing control back and forth. But it's definitely a good idea if you're just trying to do Python-style generator functions in C++.

Comment: The top thing was due to a temporary gcc bug, I fixed the code a little. Anyway there's a better coroutine class here: https://github.com/user1095108/generic/blob/master/coroutine.hpp

Comment: As for generators, you can provide a reference to the coroutine, if you want some result returned. I thought generators were not orthogonal. I know that usually coroutines are used as such, but you many not want a result returned at all so, I felt this violated the orthogonality/minimalistic design principle.

Comment: Re "the top thing": no, that's not a compiler bug AFAIK. You can write `char* top = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&top);` to fix it. But you can't refer to `top` in an expression that requires `top`'s type before `top`'s type is known. Unless I'm mistaken, that's not a compiler bug; that's just how causality works in this universe. ;)

Comment: it used to compile, or I wouldn't post it here.